# Domino effect errors/warnings in NLP package?

Tags: r, nlp

I'm working with [corpuslingr](https://github.com/jaytimm/corpuslingr) for a NLP little project. I'm following the README but I've encountered some errors when running it.

So I want to detect the frequency of occurrence of things like the use of abstract nouns or deontic modalities which include the auxiliary verbs ‘must’, ‘have to’, ‘may’, ‘can’, ‘should’, ‘ought to ’, etc. I would like to capture its possible conjugation, i.e., not only 'she have to' but 'she had to'; not only 'he can' but 'he could'.

I could use a POS tagger to do this, but I don't want to extract the information about every word in the corpus, just some words of my choice. Each text of the corpus is a political debate between two persons. We want to know if one or another use more modal verbs (so I don't want every verb analyzed), some specific abstract nouns, etc. than the other. So the thing is I don't want every term they use but rather some grammatical elements of my choice. That's why I think corpuslingr package is useful for my purposes.

So I start preprocessing the corpus

```
myStopwords = c(stopwords(kind="spanish"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords,c(stopwords = myStopwords))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
```

Tokenizing the corpus

```
myCorpusTokenized <- lapply(corpus, scan_tokenizer)
```

Stemming each token vector

```
myTokensStemCompleted <- lapply(myCorpusTokenized, stemCompletion, corpus)
```

Concatenating tokens by document and creating a data frame

```
myDf <- data.frame(text = sapply(myTokensStemCompleted, paste, collapse = "     "), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Starting with corpuslingr package

```
corpus1 <- clr_prep_corpus (myDf, hyphenate = TRUE)
```

Annotating the corpus data frame object (yep, I'm working with Spanish texts. Package is english-specific but I can load the spanish-ancora dictionary without problems from udpipe)

```
cleanNLP::cnlp_init_udpipe(model_name="spanish-ancora",feature_flag = FALSE, parser = "none") 
ann_corpus <- cleanNLP::cnlp_annotate(corpus1$text, as_strings = TRUE, doc_ids = corpus1$doc_id)
```

As you can read in the README from the package, this function prepares the annotated corpus for complex search (as defined above) by building  tuples and setting tuple onsets/offsets.

```
lingr_corpus <- ann_corpus$token %>%
clr_set_corpus(doc_var='id', 
              token_var='word', 
              lemma_var='lemma', 
              tag_var='pos', 
              pos_var='upos',
              sentence_var='sid',
              meta = corpus[,c('doc_id','source','search')])
```

Here comes the problem. If I run ^ this error and warning message appear

```
Error in `[.SimpleCorpus`(corpus, , c("doc_id", "source", "search")) : 
unused argument (c("doc_id", "source", "search"))
In addition: Warning message:
In order(as.numeric(names(list_dfs))) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I'm not sure if it's for the comma in the "meta" line, but if I run it without the comma:

```
Warning message:
In order(as.numeric(names(list_dfs))) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

So if I try to paste some tuple-ized with

```
paste(lingr_corpus$corpus1[[1]]$tup[200:204], collapse= " ")
```

theoretically it should give me something like (it's in English because it's pasted from the README file)

```
## [1] "<intervene~intervene~VB> <during~during~IN> <a~a~DT> <Presidential~presidential~JJ> <foreign~foreign~JJ>"
```

but if I run it, it gives me this:

```
[1] ""
```

If I keep running the commands from the README like this (1)

```
summary <- corpuslingr::clr_desc_corpus(lingr_corpus,doc="doc_id", 
                    sent="sentence_id", tok="token",upos='pos', genre="search")
```

then it throws me more and more errors :_]. Error from (1)

```
Error in setDT(corp$meta) : Item 'meta' not found in names of input list
```

(2)

```
search1 <- "ADV"

lingr_corpus %>%
corpuslingr::clr_search_gramx(search=search1)%>%
select(doc_id, search, token, tag)%>% 
slice(1:15)
```

error from (2)

```
Error in corpuslingr::clr_search_gramx(., search = search1) : 
SEARCH TERM(S) NOT FOUND.  See corpuslingr::clr_search_egs for example CQL & syntax.
```

So yeah, I'm not sure if the problem is at the first error I encountered or it's just that it doesn't work with spanish as good as with english. I would like to know if it's like a domino effect and I should fix from the first error it gave me or it's just not possible with spanish.

Comment: Can you start with a reproducible example. We don't have your `corpus` data.

Comment: How can I do it? Should I upload to Google Drive some of the documents from my corpus or should I paste them directly in the post? Thanks for your reply.